# Google Sheet Conditional Formatting Custom Formula Wild Card

Tags: google-sheets

How do we use wildcard in custom formula in Google Sheet Conditional Formatting?

I tried `=F1="ID-*"` (Applied on G1) and this doesn't seem to work. It does nothing. Some of the values in column F starts with the text "ID-" and I want G to change color if that's the case. I searched Google for this for the past months and frustrated because of no working result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
=REGEXMATCH(F1,"^ID-")
```

[image]

Or, simpler, since it's in the beginning you can just use LEFT:

```
=LEFT(F1,3)="ID-"
```

[image]

Comment: PS: I applied it to column F in my examples, but you can do the same to column G obviously